# The definition of letters on electrical wires

Tags: electrical

I find letter definitions for everything except the (B), example... TYPE NM-B.
NM= Non-Metalic.
What does the "B" indicate?

Answer (score 6):

The NM means "non-metallic sheathed", not simply "non-metallic".  The 'B' is simply a revision letter, indicating the mandated upgrade to the conductors' temperature ratings implemented in 1984.